How to get keys of constant dictionary as union of literal string
In Python, is there a way to get the keys of a constant dictionary as a union of string literals?
TL;DR does Python have something like TypeScript's keyof operator?
In TypeScript, I can infer possible keys on a readonly/const object as a union of literals.
const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
} as const;

type Keys = keyof typeof obj1;
//  "a" | "b" | "c"

If I want to do similarly in Python, I would do
from typing import Literal, Dict

Keys = Literal['a', 'b', 'c']
DICT1: Dict[Keys, int] = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}

Is there a way to infer Keys from DICT1, instead of having to define it myself? It gets tedious if I have a dict with 10+ entries. I don't want to have to write the keys twice (once in the dictionary and again in a Literal/Enum.) I haven't seen a solution that doesn't involve writing the data twice or losing type information (ie: Dict[str, int]).
If there's a way to denote that this dictionary is constant/readonly so that the language server can infer more information about keys/values, I'm okay with that.

You probably need to change your approach. What is that constant dict meant to be used for?

Second InSync: if you want to do this, you likely want a dataclass/namedtuple/Pydantic/... and not a dict. There is TypedDict also, but it does not help with "do not repeat keys twice" requirement. But I really fail to understand what you're trying to achieve, please show more context. How will Keys type be used?

DICT1 is a mapping of a large, but finite collection of external (human-readable) ids that map to internal ids. I want to have Keys as a type that I can reuse elsewhere (ie: a function parameter's type).

Regarding your last point

If there's a way to denote that this dictionary is constant/readonly so that the language server can infer more information about keys/values, I'm okay with that.

Maybe typing.Final would help here?
from typing import Dict, Final

DICT1: Final[Dict[str, int]] = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}

Note that this is strictly a typing annotation and is not enforced at runtime.

AFAIK that doesn't fix my problem, but I did not know about Final and will likely be using it a lot in the future

Consider extracting arguments from Literal. Maybe this snippet will help. In python in such cases you usually infer values from Literal to dictionary.
from typing import Literal, Dict, List, get_args

Keys = Literal['a', 'b', 'c']
keys: List[Keys] = list(get_args(Keys))

data = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(keys)}


I tried the following
keys = get_args(Keys) # tuple[Any, ...]
but it loses type information

yes, that's why you add typing hint to 'keys' (keys: List[Keys] = ...). In this case annotation persist. Try adding smth like this:  from typing import Tuple
keys: Tuple[Keys] =get_args(Keys)

If I use keys: Tuple[Keys] = get_args(Keys), do similarly with Values, and then dict(zip(...)), that gets closest to what I want. I still lose some type information (compared to TS), and I think this means I'm incurring a (negligible) runtime cost in having to both create the lists and construct the dictionary (as opposed to just creating the dictionary), but the resulting dictionary has an inferred type of Dict[Keys, Values] which is good

Also in python 3.11 or newer you can try this snippet. Community claim that it works:
tt = [1,2,3,4,5]
Keys = Literal[*tt]

@JohnnyCheesecutter Who is "Community"? Literal[] does not accept unpacked arguments.
